# GO: Run cli command with wrong args

Tags: go, command-line, command-line-interface, go-cobra

I use cobra to create CLI command tool.
everything is looking OK except the error handling

what I want that if command was sent by mistake (wrong args or wrong input) return **std.err** instead of **std.out**

to simplify the secnario I've created this which demonstrate my use-case

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

var (
    RootCmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use: "myApp",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Printf("ROOT verbose = %d, args = %v\n", args)
        },
    }

    provideCmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use: "provide",
        Run: nil,
    }

    appCmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use: "apps",
        RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            name := args[0]
            if name != "myapp" {
                err := errors.New("app name doesnt exist")
                return err
            }
            return nil
        },
        SilenceUsage:               true,
    }


)

func init() {
    // Add the application command to app command
    provideCmd.AddCommand(appCmd)
    //  add provide command to root command
    RootCmd.AddCommand(provideCmd)
}

func main() {
    if err := RootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
}
```

Now if I compile the binary and run `exec.Command` against the binary everything is working as expected. but if I want to test the error scenario like `mycli provide apps apps1`
I want to see that returned in `std.err` and not at `std.out`

When I execute `mycli provide apps myapp` everything should be OK

but if I run `mycli provide apps myapp2` I want to get std.err and not std.out , which is not the case here ...what am I missing here ?

https://play.golang.org/p/B00z4eZ7Sj-

Comment: One way is to write the error using the `os` package via `os.Stderr.WriteString(err)` instead of doing `fmt.Println(err)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample already prints the error both to `stdout` and `stderr`.

By default the `cobra` package prints any errors it encounters to `stderr`, unless you specifically change that.

So running 
`./main provide apps something 2> ./stderr.txt` creates a text file with the following content (this is what cobra writes to `stderr` without your intervention):

```
Error: app name doesnt exist
```

And running `./main provide apps something > ./stdout.txt` - creates a text file with the following content (you printed that yourself with `fmt.Println(err)`, the second line from the bottom in your code):

```
app name doesnt exist
```

Which means **default behaviour prints errors both to `stdout` and `stderr`**.

As Devin has advised you, changing the last line to `os.Stderr.WriteString(err)` or
`fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)` (the one I would use) will make your project to  **print everything to `stderr` only**, which means printing errors twice:

```
Error: app name doesnt exist
app name doesnt exist
```

It might be useful to know that cobra allows you some control of error printing behaviour. For example, you can tell a cobra command which stream to print to:

```
command.SetOutput(os.Stdout)     // Defaults to os.Stderr
```

you could also prevent printing of errors:

```
command.SilenceErrors = true
```

or prevent printing of usage text:

```
command.SilenceUsage = true
```